# How create facebook ads based on.user last activity on our website?

Tags: facebook

We have an e commerce website with mobiles,laptops,books and clothing.

All these have different search pages where user can.filter the results.

I want to show the ad of user's last visited page on our website. I want to show the ad on facebook only In case user has made no transaction on our website.

Airbnb,Amazon is doing the same thing. Can this be done only when user is logged into facebook from same browser? How does facebook get user information, how it identifies and map this user on its website?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/facebook-ads-pixel

Answer (score 2):

The product you are looking for is Facebook retargeting. You place a Facebook pixel code on your site, then define from your Facebook ads dashboard what the conditions are for your retargeting.

Like most types of tracking it works by having cookies dropped when a person visits a site.

Comment: okay. interesting. any idea which cookie facebook sets? what is contained in that cookie? and can we retarget users based on particular cookies?